# How to make Distribution Commits

Tags: git

I saw it in [this repo](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/tree/v1.1.2).

My doubt is, how is that the tags of releases point to branch with just one commit? How do you do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to do such a thing? It doesn't make too much sense, what is the use-case?

Anyway, just make a new orhpan branch with `git checkout --orphan`, then create a commit, tag it and eventually delete the branch again. Et voilá, you have a tag that points to a commit without history and not on any branch.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned that repo and looked at the commit you're talking about using `log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --graph --decorate --all` which

It looks like they made a release branch (see `origin/release`) on the `master` branch, committed a few distribution changes, then tagged it as `v1.2.0`.

The tagged release is therefore on its own branch but keeps the history up to the point of branching.

You can see the content of the two commits on the `release` branch by running `git show <commit reference>`.